# How to use filter on query_entities

Tags: python, azure

I want to use a filter on query_entities for Azure table storage.

I have tried to use filter like this : 
Table = table_service.query_entities('MyTableName', filter = "RowKey eq 20")

```
#coding:utf-8
import os
import json
from azure import *
from azure.storage import *
from azure.storage.table import TableService, Entity

table_service = TableService(account_name='MyAccountName', 
sas_token='MySASToken')
Table  = table_service.query_entities('MyTableName', filter = "Country eq 
USA")
print(Table.items)
```

I got an exception:

> azure.common.AzureHttpError: Bad Request
>   {"odata.error":{"code":"InvalidInput","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A
>   binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand
>   types 'Edm.String' and 'Edm.Int32' for operator kind
>   'Equal'.\nRequestId:ef3858e7-5002-00d0-617f-0d374a000000\nTime:2019-05-18T13:45:23.6288160Z"}}}

And I have tried changing to this :

```
Table  = table_service.query_entities('MyTableName', filter = "Country eq 
USA")
```

But I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for filter:

```
Country eq 'USA'
```

Basically your attribute's data type is `String` hence the value needs to be in single quotes.

Same thing applies for your `RowKey` query as well:

```
RowKey eq '20'
```

You can find more examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#sample-query-expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You got the first exception because of the equal comparison: `"Country eq 
USA"`.

Check your table description, in exception message it's said you are doing "Found operand types 'Edm.String' and 'Edm.Int32' for operator kind 'Equal'". `Country` is likely be `Edm.Int32`, so make sure you are comparing the same type.

And the second exception though you didn't post full traceback I suspect you deleted the last line's parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it's work fine :

```
Table  = table_service.query_entities('MyTableName', filter = "Country eq 
'USA'")
```